# Modern List - Force New Item Button To Open NewForm.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-online

So i'm trying to figure out if there is a way to make the (+New) button on a modern list, point to the NewForm.aspx page instead of the overlapping slide out form you commonly see with modern lists now.

I have some 3rd party software that does not function with the overlapping form, but works great in Classic Mode on the NewForm.aspx page.

Comment: This is not working any more now . Can you please share any other alternatives ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can customize the NewForm.aspx, then it will open the NewForm.aspx instead of the overlapping slide when clicking "+New" on the modern list view.

The customization on the NewForm.aspx can be a small part.

For example:

1. Return to the classic view and edit the NewForm.aspx, add a Script Editor web part without any script (leave it blank) to the NewForm.aspx.
2. Save the NewForm.aspx.
3. Exist the classic view. Try clicking "+New", you will get the NewForm.aspx instead of the overlapping slide.

Comment: It looks like this workaround doesn't work anymore.